# How to remove one role from everything on the server?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a code to remove one role from everyone on the server, but it doesn't work:
When I enter a command, the bot simply ignores it, there is nothing in the cmd and the bot does not do anything either

Code -

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True

@client.command()
async def clearrole(ctx):
    
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = 795410455848812565)
    members = ctx.guild.members
   
    
    for member in members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: You could add print statements to see if each scope is being executed

Comment: Have a look @Nathan Marotte 's answer. You need member intents.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the intents are enabled, otherwise your bot might not be able to get a list of all the members of your server : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Then, make sure the id indeed correspond to a role by typing <@795410455848812565> in your server, it should transform into the role mention, otherwise the ID is wrong

Comment: I turned on the intents as shown in the link and tried to mention the role, but it really didn't change and tried it with a few more, but they didn't change either.

Comment: What happens if you print all your variables step by step ? Does `role` is shown as None or as the role you want it to be ? What about members, is it a list of Members? 
Printing the type of the variables as well could help.

Does your code ever reach the line `member.remove_roles(role)` ? (print right before and right after)

Also, does your bot somewhere catches errors ? (on_command_error or on_error listeners) If so, you might wanna check in case you catch an error and don't process it, do you raise it again? If not, this might hide a useful Traceback